# Earliest date possible for submitting my tax declaration in Germany?

Tags: germany, taxes

Driven by my [personal catastasis](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/146801/can-avoid-asking-for-a-later-start-date), I would like to know when is the earliest date I can submit my tax declaration in Germany?

I want to do it only for year 2019, and I have only my job (no extra income, no property).

My company will give me the [Lohnsteuerbescheinigung](https://blog.dendax.com/en/what-is-a-lohnsteuerbescheinigung-when-will-you-receive-it) in early Feb 2019. However, I can sum up all the amounts from the monthly payrolls, and fill the tax declaration with these amounts.

So I was hoping that I could submit the tax declaration in January, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you can do it even on January, 1st.

Comment: Thank you @ExPatriot, seems you are right, I managed to go today to the Finanzamt and ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tax Forms can be found here [Formular-Management-System der Bundesfinanzverwaltung](https://www.formulare-bfinv.de/ffw/content.do?%24csrf=8F83ZIEDCV737JL6I73S952RT)

- select **Steuerformulare**

A list of different types will be shown

- select **Einkommensteuer** (Income tax)

A list of the different years will be shown

- 2019 is not yet being offered

After selecting a year (2018), all available forms will be listed

- **001 - Anleitungen zur Einkommensteuererklärung (2018)**

  - list of instructions for each type of form will be offered

    - selecting one will download a corresponding pdf
- The other forms can either be filled out online or be downloaded as pdf

  - select the pdf icon to download the pdf form
  - select the text discription to open the online form

    - **Note** a timeout of 45 minutes exists
    - the filled out form can be downloaded as pdf
    - an empty form can be downloaded
    - the instructions can be downloaded

---

Once the form is being offered, you can prepare it and submit it on the first working day of the year (2nd of January 2020).

---

If you are giving notice to your employer anyway, ask them to expedite the issuing of the Lohnsteuerbescheinigung, so that you can compleate the application in the first weeks of January.

Comment: Your link is timed out.

Comment: @ExPatriot Yes, it uses a session cookie. Link has been corrected and instructions added to find the proper income tax directory. Further instructions on how to use.

Comment: @MarkJohnson the Einkommensteuer for 2019 will be offered in December 2018, I asked the Finanzamt. Thanks for the tip about the Lohnsteuerbescheinigung, but if my current company fails to do so, I will attempt to sum up all the amounts from the monthly payrolls (the one of December is issued on mid December), and fill the Tax Declaration (Einkommensteuer) based on these amounts.